# Why does rubocop or the ruby style guide prefer not to use get_ or set_?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I was running [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop) on my project and fixing the complaints it raised.

One particular complaint bothered me

> Do not prefix reader method names with get_

I could not understand much from this complaint so I looked at [source code in github](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/accessor_method_name.rb).

I found this snippet

```
def bad_reader_name?(method_name, args)
  method_name.start_with?('get_') && args.to_a.empty?
end

def bad_writer_name?(method_name, args)
  method_name.start_with?('set_') && args.to_a.one?
end
```

So to summarize:

1. Rubocop advises against using `get_` when the method does not have arguments; otherwise they allow `get_`.
2. Rubocop advises against using `set_` when the method has only one argument; otherwise they allow `set_`.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: For purely curiosity's sake, what is the method name?

Answer (score 15):

I think the point here is ruby devs prefer to always think of methods as getters since they returns something and use the equals "syntactic sugar" (like in `def self.dog=(params)` which lets you do `Class.dog = something`). In essence the point I've always seen made is that the get and set are redundant and verbose.

In opposition to this you have get and set with multiple args which are like finder methods (particularly get; think of ActiveRecord's `where`).

Keep in mind that 'style guide' = pure opinion. Consistency is the higher goal of style guides in general so unless something is arguably wrong or difficult to read, your goal should be more on having everything the same than of a certain type. Which is why rubocop let's you turn this off.

Comment: Ok . this is convincing . can I make ruby cop skip that line from being checked ?

Comment: Well.. you can make it skip the file or just take it off completely in the config. This way it will never complain, but then it won't notify you when you're using `get_` in any of the files.(Which you sound ok with?) You can change it in your rubocop [config file](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml)

Comment: I don't want to do it for the entire app so , I added the comment # # rubocop:disable Style/AccessorMethodName # rubocop:enable Style/AccessorMethodNamefor that block alone .

Answer (score 9):

Another way to see it: the getter/setter paradigm was, as far as I can tell, largely a specific convention in Java/C++ etc.; at least I knew quite a few Java codebases in the very foggy past where Beans were littered with huge amounts of get_-getters and set_-setters. In that time, the private attribute would likely be called "name" with "set_name()" and "get_name()"; as the attribute itself was called "name", the getter could not be "name()" as well.

Hence the very existence of "get_" and "set_" is due to a (trivial) technical shortcoming of languages that do not allow the "=" in method names.

In Ruby, we have quite a different array of possibilities:

- First and foremost, we have `name()` and `name=()`, which immediately removes the need for the `get_` and `set_` syntax. So, we *do* have getters and setters, we just call them differently from Java.
- Also, the attribute then is not `name` but `@name`, hence solving this conflict as well.
- Actually, you don't have attributes with the plain "obj.name" syntax at all! For example, while Rails/ActiveRecord pretends that `person.name` is an "attribute", it is in fact simply a pair of auto-generated getter `name()` and setter `name=()`. Conceptually, the caller is not supposed to care about what "name" is (attribute or method), it is an implementation detail of the class.
- It saves 4 or 3 key presses for each call. This might seem like a joke, but writing concise yet easily comprehensible code *is* a trademark of Ruby, after all. :-)

Comment: Great answer! It might still make sense to have `set_` (setting global states) and `get_` (`get_headers`, `post_headers`, `delete_headers` (as HTTP verbs)). But it should definitely not be used as Java-style accessors (e.g. `attr_accessor` can do that :D)

Comment: Nice example `get_headers`. That's where `#rubocop:disable` will come in handy, then. ;) @Dorian

Answer (score -1):

The way I understand it is that it's because `foo.get_value` is imperative and `foo.value` is declarative.